# Basic autocomplete function with result limit

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I've got this basic autocomplete function which works just fine.
But I want to change it to show the matching result even if input has no further matches.

**For example:**

**Dictionary**: Metallica, Metaphor, Melancholic, Meditation, Mercury

Input → **Meta**
Suggestions → **Meta**llica, **Meta**phor

Input → **Metan**
Suggestions → **Meta**llica, **Meta**phor (keep showing even no match for **Metan** because **Meta** still has a matchings)

And also I want to limit the visible suggestions to a certaion number.
So basically the function will have 3 vars

**Example:**

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr, results_limit){}
```

The function I am currently using:

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {

  var currentFocus;
 
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
         
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
               
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. That one was acutally really easy.

Here is the whole code for those who might need it

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr, limit) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

            for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase() || arr[i].substr(0, val.length-1).toUpperCase() == val.substr(0, val.length-1).toUpperCase())   {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
   // execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):   
            b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }         
      }
  });   
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var args= ['Metallica', 'Metaphor', 'Melancholic', 'Meditation', 'Mercury'];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), args, 2);
```